# setting all values in a 2d array to a specific value

Tags: arrays, 2d

I am trying to create a method that will take inputs of row column and value to then create a 2d array with the specified dimensions and the input value as the value in every spot in the array. This is what I have come up with

```java
  public static int[][] makeArray(int r, int c, int v) {
    int[][] arr = new int[r][c];
    for (int i = 0; i <= c; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j <= r; j++) {
        arr[i][j] = v;
      }
    }
    return arr;
  }
```

However I seem to be getting this error
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 10 out of bounds for length 10`

Could someone help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Arrays indices starts from `0`, so if your array's `length` is `10` it means that max index (or the index of last element) is `9`.

Solution:

```java
  public static int[][] makeArray(int r, int c, int v) {
    int[][] arr = new int[r][c];
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < r; j++) {
        arr[i][j] = v;
      }
    }
    return arr;
  }
```